# How to utilize inheritance in a multi-module maven project so each sub-module can be deployed separately?

Tags: inheritance, maven, module

I am working on a very large multi-module maven project and I recently applied inheritance in it. The whole thing works fine, even each module gets packaged well. (Effective pom has everything it needs due to inheritance)

However, there are other teams that are using sub-modules independent of the large project.

I check the pom in the created jar file but it is neither effective pom nor even a pom that keeps necessary dependencies. It is exactly the one that I have in sub-module ...

Is there anyway I can use inheritance while sub-modules are still independently usable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `<parent>` section in the pom of your submodule if it needs to be part of the multi-module project.

However, the sub-module is still independently usable.  When you run a maven goal on the submodule, it automatically pulls in inherited items from the parent pom (thanks to the `<parent>` section).

Comment: Of course, I have a parent pom. And it uses inheritance to make effective pom. However, module could not be used separately for other projects. What I finally ended up doing was instead of ../parent-pom.xml I used a concrete url that other teams also had access.